# Has anyone managed to bring a useable StaticInstruction pointer from execution to Memory in Gem5?

Tags: gem5

I have been trying to have instruction information at Memory level so that I can track some specific data packets at DRAM level. So far trying to do this has not been fruitful, because from what I can see information about the instruction is needed to do the filtering, and bringing a *StatiInst pointer* or object into memory's context has not been going great. [Segmentation faults or the distribution becoming unusable from the edits].

Has anyone did this before ? If so, any pointers will be appreciated.